# Sum specific rows whilst ignoring one column

Tags: pandas

I'm comparing old and new data collection techniques. I need to sum over one column whilst leaving the other column(s) untouched. My dataframe looks like this:

```
          new   old
apples    25    11
pears     12    4
apples    25    5
apples    25    8
bananas   5     1
pears     12    9
bananas   5     5
```

The new data collection techniques always produce the right answer, but the old ones produced different answers based on the technique that was used. I don't want to touch the values from the new technique, and I want to sum the values for the old technique to leave me with:

```
          new   old
apples    25    24
pears     12    13
bananas   5     6
```

I'm fairly sure that groupby is my friend for this one, but can't work out how to populate the new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right, groupby is your friend. Try the foloowing:

```
df.groupby('new').old.sum().reset_index()

    new old
0   5   6
1   12  13
2   25  24
```

Note that you will lose the index of your original dataframe though.

If you want to keep your index you could do the following:

```
my_df = my_df.reset_index().groupby('index').agg({'new':'first','old':'sum'})
del my_df.index.name

        old new
apples  24  25
bananas 10  5
pears   9   12
```

If you don't care about your original index, I suggest you use the former as it is more efficient:

```
%timeit my_df.groupby('new').old.sum().reset_index()
817 µs ± 2.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit my_df.reset_index().groupby('index').agg({'new':'first','old':'sum'})
1.33 ms ± 1.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Fantastic! That works. I'm using your first suggestion, because I don't care about the index. Will take a note of the second option though. Thank you!